# Excel Find the first zero after a non zero within a range

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a range, that contains data which follows a distribution *typically starts at 0, then goes up, then down, and finally back to zero.
I want to return the value of another column at the point that the data returns back to Zero  (in my case you can see that Cell B6 is the point at which this event occurs, and I want my cell C2 to return the value "E" from cell A6...

[image]

Currently, the best I can get to is the following:

```
=INDEX(A2:B8,FIND(0,
TEXTJOIN(,,B2:B8),
MATCH(AGGREGATE(4,4,B2:B8),B2:B8,0)) -1,1)
```

The problem comes in with the fact that there can be any number of zeros before the data appears.
i.e. like this.  = Where I would still expect the highlighted match.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1] 1st zero after a non-zero value, in `C2` enter formula :

```
=INDEX(A:A,INDEX(MATCH(1,1/B:B),0)+1)
```

2] Nos. of zero after a non-zero value, in `D2` enter formula :

```
=MATCH(9^9,B:B)-INDEX(MATCH(1,1/B:B),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For excel you can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B2:B8)/(B2:B8=0),2))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want get first zero value after last non zero value use formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(B2:B8)/(B2:B8<>0),1)+1)
```

Comment: Thanks. this is very elegant. however one issue is that I dont know how many 0's will exist before the data